# Read xml file pandas from given tag

Tags: python, pandas

My xml data is as follows,

[image]

I want output dataframe as

| English | Marathi |
| --- | --- |
| prompt_username | वापरकर्त्याचे नाव |
| item | आगमन चेतावणी |

The output is kind of english to marathi table.

I tried with following code:

```
xml_file = et.parse("strings_Marathi.xml")
for item in xml_file.iterfind('string name='):
    print(item)
```

I could find string tage but how can I extract string name="" ?

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is an attribute of the element `string`. To get the attribute value, you use the property `.attrib` which is a dictionary.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
<foo>
<string name="abc">123</string>
<string name="def">456</string>
<string>789</string>
<string name="jkl">000</string>
</foo>
'''

f = StringIO(data)
tree = ET.parse(f) # replace with ET.parse("strings_Marathi.xml") to load your file

for tag in tree.iterfind('.//string[@name]'):
    print(tag.attrib['name'], tag.text)
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin Ezequiel, you have used sample data, how to  read the xml file before stringIO?

Comment: You already have a `tree` with your call to `xml_file = et.parse("strings_Marathi.xml")`. You've also shown that you can call `xml_file.iterfind(...)` which is equivalent to my `tree.iterfind(...)`. So what's your problem? Or did you just copy-paste that code from somewhere without understanding what it does?